# Add UILabels in swift on viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, tvos

I am trying to add UILabels programmatically in the viewDidLoad method, below code works when called on a button press but not onViewDidLoad. I want the labels to be display as soon as the view is loaded onto the screen for the first time.

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
        super.viewDidLoad()

        BarGraphView.isRandomColor = true
        let labelsArray:[String] = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"]
        var graphPoints: [CGFloat] = [4,8,6,8,5,6,8]

        bar.plotGraph(labelsArray, data: graphPoints)
        lineGraph.plotGraph(labelsArray, data: graphPoints,view: view)

        for i in 0..<lineGraph.graphXAxisPoints.count {

            print("graph x point ==>"+String(lineGraph.graphXAxisPoints.count))
            let labelWidth: CGFloat = 20.0
            var tempLabel  = UILabel()
            print("i value ==>"+String(i))
            var point: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: lineGraph.graphXAxisPoints[i] - labelWidth/2, y: CGFloat( lineGraph.bounds.height - 20) )


            tempLabel.frame = CGRect(origin: point, size: CGSize(width: labelWidth, height: 10))

            tempLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            tempLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            tempLabel.tag = i+1
            tempLabel.text = labelsArray[i]**


            lineGraph.addSubview(tempLabel)

            let view1 = lineGraph.viewWithTag(i+1)

            lineGraph.addSubview(view1!)

        }


        print("refreshing")
        self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
        lineGraph.setNeedsLayout()
    }
```

Comment: What does `print(lineGraph.graphXAxisPoints.count)`  print to the console? Why do you have two asterisks in `tempLabel.text = labelsArray[i]**`? Where is `view1` defined as used in `lineGraph.addSubview(view1!)`?

Comment: The reason it likely doesn't work in `viewDidLoad` is that the views have not yet been laid out, and thus values like `lineGraph.bounds.height` are not yet reliable. You can either defer it until later in the view build process (e.g. `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`), or even better, use constraints.

Comment: Unrelated, but the last two lines in the `for` loop are redundant. You just added `tempLabel` with a particular `tag` value to `lineGraph`, so there's no point in the getting a reference to that view by its tag only to add it back to the same `lineGraph` it was already added to. Furthermore, `setNeedsDisplay` and `setNeedsLayout` are unnecessary, too.

Answer (score 0):

You should put this code in `viewWillAppear()` then it should work.